# SSRS export to Excel only shows top few rows

Tags: reporting-services

I've got an SSRS (2014) report with a few expandable groups. They expand and contract just fine in the report viewer. But if they are hidden when I export to Excel, the Excel file will have the plus signs on the sign to expand the groups, but when you click on them, it only will reveal the first few rows; the rest seem to be in some inaccessible no-man's land. After searching around for awhile, the only possible thing I could find was changing DataElementOutput in the boxes, but that didn't do anything. For example the list is clients, clicking on client expands the list of projects for that client. Client #2 is at row 62, Client #3 at row 195. I expand Client #2 and it shows the first project(row 63) and I expand that for project details (rows 64-65), but the rest of the projects and details for this client(rows 66-194) remains hidden and inaccessible.

[image]

Comment: you've probably tried this but just in case... select a bunch of rows and set the row height to something like 15 (default). It may be they all have a row height of zero. Or try to Unhide them from the same right-click context menu

Comment: It looks like the visibility for Rows 66 - 194 is controlled by the second **+** on line 6. Does that do something else? Though if it's the same data section as rows 64 and 65, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @HannoverFist The plus doesn't control that, I expanded everything and it was still the same, I just didn't hit that plus this time before doing the screenshot. Pressing that actually shows/hides the previous client that starts at row 7. It's weird, the grouping and expand/contract doesn't quite work the way you'd expect it to.

Comment: However @AlanSchofield I can't believe I didn't think of that, that did show those rows. Unfortunately the expand/contract is still messed up and so you can't just, say, collapse to the client group, I am guessing that's just a shortcoming in SSRS and how it creates the Excel files it exports

Comment: Strange though, I've not seen that before, but I don't do much a great deal  with grouped excel exports. I might setup a test report to see if I can replicate it, maybe setting `can shrink` on the rows in the report design might solve it but I'm just guessing now.

Comment: found your issue...https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2777223/workbook-contains-hidden-rows-and-columns-when-you-export-reports-from-sql-server-reporting-services-to-excel

Comment: Thanks Alan. That article from microsoft describes my problem exactly, although it didn't work for me...I changed every box to have height and width in points, but still had the same issue. I also tried changing can shrink to true, and that didn't work either. Don't know what's going on here. Although I did discover that if you use the numbers at the top to collapse/expand groups, that works fine, although you have to then have every item opened and can't specify an individual one to open.